# ACF Repeater field not seeing rows

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Have a repeater field that looks to see what the section type is and then outputs certain code base on that type. For some reason the code is always outputting "No Rows Found" even though there are rows.

I have this working already for something else but wanting to use it again to output something different its not working.

Here is the code below

```
<?php if( have_rows('layout_section') ): ?>

    <?php while(the_repeater_field('layout_section')): ?>

        <?php if (get_sub_field('layout_section_type') == "test") { ?>

            <?php the_sub_field('post_id'); ?>

        <?php } elseif ( get_sub_field('layout_section_type') == "featured" ) { ?>

            <p>Featured Section</p>

        <?php } elseif ( get_sub_field('layout_section_type') == "test2" ) { ?>

            <p>Tewsat 2</p>


        <?php } else { ?>

            <p>Normal Section</p>

        <?php } ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
else :
    echo 'No Rows Found';
    // no rows found
endif;
?>
```

Here is the config on ACF side

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbHDp.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zvP3.png

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks different to the sample code on the ACF website:

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Try swapping out your `while` for the following:

```
while ( have_rows('layout_section') ) : the_row();
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that way of doing it too and no success. I have another file for another repeater field and the code works fine. This code is the same other than the field and subfield.

I have checked to make sure it is all correct with field name etc and I do not see any errors.

Comment: Might be worth having a check over the config and options are set up ok in the options page?

Comment: Had a look at the setting but could not see anything out of place. Have updated my question to links with images of the settings.

Can't seem to work out why the exact code which works already is not working for another custom section.